# Google map computeDistanceBetween() returning NaN no typo

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I have this code below, I'm trying to execute the `computeDistanceBetween` function but it is returning NaN. There is no typo errors. I really don't know what it happening. Please help!

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id ="VP"><button onClick="getAddressFromCoord('Port-Louis')">1</button>
</div>
<div id ="VP"><button onClick="findNearestEmpl()">2</button></div>
<script>
 var emplcoordinates= [];
 var empDistance=[];
       function getAddressFromCoord(Address){
    var coordinate;
 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = 'port louis';
       geocoder.geocode({
       'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           coordinate = results[0].geometry.location.lat()+','+results[0].geometry.location.lng();
     emplcoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate));
     console.log(emplcoordinates);
        } else {
            coordinate = 0;
   emplcoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate));
   console.log(emplcoordinates);
        }
    });
 
}

function findNearestEmpl(){
 var checkpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(-20.244299955429746,57.459360252793886);
 for(i=0;i<emplcoordinates.length;i++)
 {
  empDistance.push( google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(checkpoint,emplcoordinates[i]));
  console.log('distance1 ='+empDistance[i])
 }
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***run button 1 then button 2***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that turning latitude and longitude into a string like below doesn't work:

```
coordinate = results[0].geometry.location.lat()+','+results[0].geometry.location.lng();
emplcoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate));
```

This worked for me, however:

```
emplcoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()));
```

Even simpler, if there isn't a particular reason to create a separate new LatLng object:

```
emplcoordinates.push(results[0].geometry.location);
```

The output I get is:

```
distance1 =10263.42066184296
```